# Finding the sign of $\phi$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I know its a little silly, but I got the wrong sign several times.
Just to be clear, $z=r\cos(\phi), -\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ when converting from cartesian to spherical. So, how do I determine the sign?
Thanks!

Comment: If $\phi$ here is supposed to be co-latitude, the version of spherical coordinates that I am accustomed to has it go from $0$ (North Pole) to $\pi$ (South Pole). It seems as if you're measuring from the equator instead of from the poles?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the method would be the same with little changes, wouldn't it?

Comment: If, as you claim, the changes are "little", then you can figure out how to correct $\phi=\arccos\frac{z}{r}$, which assumes measurement from the poles, to your preferred convention, no?

Comment: I just happen to be a TA in a calculus course this semester and we just got to spherical coordinates. We teach that $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$ and $z=r\cos\phi$.

Answer (score 1):

The [spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) I learned has $z=r \cos \theta$ with $0 \le \theta \le \pi$.  For that range of $\phi$ you need to use $z=r \sin(\phi)$, in which case you can get the sign.  I have seen geographers use this, though they usually use $\lambda$ for latitude